# Can't control Struts2 log level using log4j.xml

Tags: struts2, log4j

I am playing around with a Struts2 webapp (Struts 2.2.3.1) running on Tomcat 6.
As seen in several tutorials, I have the following bit in my log4j.xml, which is deployed in the webapp's WEB-INF/classes directory:

```
<logger name="com.opensymphony">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.apache.struts2">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>
```

After setting the property `log4j.debug=true` in my Tomcat confiuration, I find (as expected) the following output in the Tomcat log:

```
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "null".
log4j: Ignoring debug attribute.
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [com.opensymphony] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for com.opensymphony is  [DEBUG].
log4j: com.opensymphony level set to DEBUG
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.apache.struts2] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.apache.struts2 is  [DEBUG].
log4j: org.apache.struts2 level set to DEBUG
log4j: Level value for root is  [DEBUG].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
```

However, no Struts debugging messages can be found at all in any logfile. 
My log4j version is 1.2.14.

How can I properly control Struts' logging?

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct you have to define some sort of Appender in order to redirect the log output to the log file.

in default case struts2 log will be getting displayed on the console.Define something like this in your log4j file

```
<appender name="FA" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
<param name="File" value="sample.log"/>
<param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />
</layout>
</appender>
```

You have to tell log4j where to redirect the logout

Comment: I don't believe that's the issue. I already have a stdout appender, whose output is written to catalina.out. Normal log messages of my application are written there as they should be.

Comment: i have tons of struts2 application running on my machine even all i am placing the log4j property file inside my web-apps and strut2 showing me a lot of logs though i am not redirecting them to file :). will try fileAppender to check how it goes :)